# Recycler.View Adapter is displaying only the first and last item on the screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recycler view for medical reports.

onClick on report 1, report 0 is getting clicked.
upon Scrolling down then again onClick report 1 then the last one item report 10 is getting clicked.

So basically the **`onClick`** on the **`RecyclerView`** Item is not working properly

My `RecyclerViewHolder` is

```
private class ReportHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{ 
    //contains how a single element inside recycler view will be defined so if 
    //tick select box on scrolling the checkbox restores its normal state to avoid //this implement on  click listener 

          private TextView mTitleTextView;
          private TextView mDateTextView;
          private CheckBox mResolvedCheckBox;


          public ReportHolder(View itemView){//itemView corresponds to single item View in app
              super(itemView);
              itemView.setOnClickListener(this);//we set current state to item view listener
              mTitleTextView=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_report_title_text_view);
              mDateTextView=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_report_date_text_view);
              mResolvedCheckBox=(CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_report_resolved_checkbox);
          }
          private void bindReport(Report report){//this method binds the details of current report  to report objects
              mReport=report;
              mTitleTextView.setText(mReport.getTitle());
              mDateTextView.setText(mReport.getDate().toString());
              mResolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mReport.isResolved());
          }

          @Override
          public void onClick( View itemView ) {
              //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),mReport.getTitle()+"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ReportActivity.class);
              Intent intent=ReportPagerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(),mReport.getId());
              Log.v(Tag,"id is "+mReport.getId().toString());// in view holder mReport is variable used to acces a particular report
              startActivity(intent);
          }
 }
```

My `RecyclerViewAdapter` class for the same is

```
private class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportHolder>{
         //recycler view doesn't know nothing about report object but adapter knows //everything about the report object . 

            private List<Report> mReports;
            public ReportAdapter(List<Report>reports){
                mReports=reports;
            }

            public ReportHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent ,int viewType){
                Log.v(Tag,"ra stage 1");
                LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());//reportHolder is just a defination of  view class which needs to be constructed or assigned memory  in Adapter class
                Log.v(Tag,"ra stage 2");
                View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_report,parent,false);
                Log.v(Tag,"ra stage 3");
                return new ReportHolder(view);//

            }

            public void onBindViewHolder(ReportHolder holder,int position{
            //mandatory methods for adapter
                Log.v(Tag,"obv stage 1");
                Report report=mReports.get(position);
                Log.v(Tag,"obv stage 2");//this methods get the report at certain position
                //holder.mTitleTextView.setText(report.getTitle());
    //this method recieves the view holder object along with its position and binds the view object to recycler view
                holder.bindReport(report);
                Log.v(Tag,"obv stage 3");//here report is local variable
            }

            public  int getItemCount(){//mandatory methods for adapter
                return mReports.size();
            }
      }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm struggling with the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

`mReport` should be a field of `ReportHolder`, at this point it's meaningless - `onClick` will always open last `ReportHolder` that was bound, regardless of which one was clicked.

Comment: mReports is static store of report each report is uniquely identified by UUID field

Comment: @ShouryaGupta I mean `mReport` not `mReports` - first line of your `bindReport()` method. Your code sample actually doesn't show this field declaration, but it's the problem because it's referred the moment when `onClick` is called.